# Custom Object Binding in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

is custom object binding possible in struts2

For example i have a date attribute in my model,  now how can i  bind this from a jsp page (input). What i am doing currently is i am creating one more attribute which is a String and then parsing this value and setting it in date object.

I Spring we have custom binders which can do this without creating and extra attribute/variable.

is there a same way in struts2 .?

Edited : `private Date dob;`
`<input name="dob" id="dob" value="" type="text" size="30"/>`

When i do this the value is not binding ..

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by parsing and even in spring when you do object binding you need to specify fields in your object which you want to map from your JSP.Its better to show the code part which is your point of confusion

Comment: you have 2 options here, either you need to have getter and setter method for your dob or with S2 2.1+ version make the field public and param interceptor will fill the value for you without any getter and setter

Comment: i have the getters and setters ..  i think u have not got what exactly i want .. actually from the input field we get string values and this is a date object so date cannot be bind ,. hope u got what i want to ask

Comment: type conversion will be done by S2 for Date out of the box, do u see any error or any warning in the console? from the UI any value regardless of what will always be submitted to the server as String in key-value format

Comment: ya u are right that the type conversion should be done by S2 but in my case it is not , neither  i am getting any errors the value is :
`21/Jul/2012 06:27 PM`

Comment: it is because S2 use `SHORT` format for the Locale associated with the current request

Comment: you mean to say like `dd/MM/yy` ?

Comment: if you need to pass date as per your way and your format all you need to define a custom type convertor